# Using Firebase Security rules, how can I check for available usernames without making the entire node public?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

In my Firebase database, I have a section for storing usernames that are taken.
There is a “usernames” node, where the username is the key, and the user’s ID is stored in a “userId” atrribute.

```
usernames
{
    username1
        userId : "exampleId1"
    username2
        userId : "exampleId2"
    username3
        userId : "exampleId3"
    ...
}
```

When a user is signing up, before they create an account and are Authenticated, the app must check that the username is not taken.

In order for this to work, the “usernames” node has been set to public in the Firebase Security Rules:

```
"usernames": {
  ".read": true
}
```

Unfortunately, this will make every taken username and internal user ID visible, which is a security concern and not something that should be done.

(for those that don’t know, public nodes can be accessed through a browser like so):

```
https://mydatabasename.firebaseio.com/usernames.json
```

There are other nodes for banned usernames and emails that work in a similar way; they have to be checked before a user is Authenticated, and should not be fully exposed to the public.

**My question is: When a user is signing up, how can I check for available usernames without making the entire node public?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know if a specific user name is already taken, the user doesn't need read permission to `/usernames` but it's suffice to give them read access to `/usernames/$username`. So:

```
"usernames": {
  "$username": {
    ".read": true
  }
}
```

With these rules, you code can check whether the specific user name that the user wants to claim is already taken (by someone else), but they can't request a list of all user names.

Comment: THANK YOU, this is the exact solution I was searching for! I tested it out and everything seems to work.

Comment: Glad to hear that was it Michael. 

Answer (score 1):

Two options comes to mind, the first is allowing the public read access to your database while the second method is what I would do in a real project:

**Method 1: Maintain a Separate "Usernames" Node**

With this method you create a secondary node, let's say it's called `usernamesInUse` and this would be world readable.  Its structure would look like this:

```
{
  "usernamesInUse": {
    "username1": true,
    "username2": true,
    "username3": true
  }
}
```

Checking if a username exists is as simple as:

`db().ref('usernamesInUse/username2').once('value', (snapshot) => if (snapshot.exists()) ...)`

The downsides to this method are that you have to have processes in place to update this node whenever a new user is added, modified or deleted.  However this would give secure read access to usernames and nothing else.

**Method 2: Create a Cloud Function (How I would do it)**

Create a simple Cloud Function with an HTTPS endpoint that checks for the existence of the username and returns a 200 or 404 status code.  Your database would not need any world readable permissions.

This avoids the need to duplicate data, prevents users from downloading a full list of every user in your system and prevents the world from unmetered access to your database.  You also have the opportunity to block access to abusive anonymous visitors.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. For now, I will likely go with Method 1 by creating a duplicate node where the userId's aren't visible. I haven't used cloud functions yet, but thank you for suggesting it so I can learn how they work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if you like the idea. :)

I would create a singleton with all func and variable private which will only return a Bool and take Username variable.
This way no one can access data or func from this part. No injections possible.

Insisde the singleton you can check all usernames and do whatever you want.
return only Bool.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I am not familliar with singletons and will have to do more research. I was wondering if this could be done using Firebase security rules only

Comment: I have used firebase a little and I don't know what could possibly do it.
I could be mistaken though. 
Firebase is not a server it's a 'smart' database

Comment: Singletons are very easy. It's a design pattern widely used.
check this out :) https://medium.com/@nimjea/singleton-class-in-swift-17eef2d01d88